# Is there possible to use Cookie and Token base authentication in same app in asp.net core app 2.1?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I have a case when I need to use 2 type of auth in one Web app:
for MVC part of app - Cookie base auth, and for Angular part JWT Token base auth.
I would like to use configuration approach over annotation.

In the setup.cs I would like to configure: all controlles methods that have /api/* in the URL path to use JWT token base auth and all controlles methods that haven't /api/* to use Cookie.

To implement this, I use two policies in the combination with custom AuthorizeFilter:

```
var jwtPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();

var cookiePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();

options.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeFilter(jwtPolicy, applyOnPath: "/api"));
options.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeFilter(cookiePolicy, notApplyOnPath: "/api"));
```

Ande here is implementation of CustomAuthorizeFilter:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : AuthorizeFilter
{
    private string _applyOnPath;
    private string _notApplyOnPath;

    public CustomAuthorizeFilter(AuthorizationPolicy policy, string applyOnPath = null, string notApplyOnPath = null) : base(policy)
    {
        _applyOnPath = applyOnPath;
        _notApplyOnPath = notApplyOnPath;
    }

    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (_applyOnPath != null && context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_applyOnPath) == true)
            return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);

        else if (_notApplyOnPath != null && context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_notApplyOnPath) == false)
            return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);

        else //Otherwise apply this policy
            return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

It was work fine in the .netCore 2.0, but after upgrade to .netCore 2.1.* it stop working...

Does anybody have a idea whet is the problem?

Comment: Cookies will be sent with AJAX requests.  Why do you think you need multiple authentication schemes?

Comment: All api-es use JWT token auth. We need it for mobile apps, for server-srerver communication, SPA app.... It is mandatory. We use Cookies only in the MVC part of app (e.g configuration pages, log pages, about pages, dev info mages...)

Comment: In that case you may find it easier to separate your API and MVC projects.  Use JWT for API and Cookies for MVC.

Comment: Can you not add the configuration parts from your cookie as claims in the JWT instead?